# Left Outer Join table is scanned and how to prevent it

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, query-optimization

After checking performance of query, I found that optimizer is scanning a small table(30000 rows). The table is small but io="Scan count 1, **logical reads 21745**, physical reads 20, read-ahead reads 154, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0" it's big.

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.name
     , a.start_dt
     , a.end_dt
     , a.title
     , b.contents
     , b.status
     , b.img
     , b.type
FROM            dbo.a WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT c.contents
                      , c.status
                      , c.img
                      , c.type
                 FROM dbo.c WITH(NOLOCK)
                 JOIN dbo.d WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.id = d.id
                 WHERE c.onoff='on' AND c.type!='S') b 
             ON a.code = b.id AND b.type='A'
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.e WITH(NOLOCK) 
             ON a.name = e.name AND e.type ='E'
```

Column "*c.id*" is primary key of the table c.

At first I think, for accessing the table c, anyway it needs to use c.id, PK. To prevent scan, when I add `from dbo.c with(nolock, forceseek)`, everything's fine with clustered index seek.

Is this just normal mistake of optimizer? And is this the only way to improve its performance? But I can't add any useful column to condition clause to use index on table c. What can I do?

Comment: It's not safe to use `NOLOCK` on queries, as you may have wrong output data due to potential concurrent transactions...

Comment: Adding optimizer hints are not advised and should really be necessary in a vanishingly small number of situations. Why are you using `nolock`? Probably you can refactor your query to use *apply* and *exists* any other advice would require the schema and indexes on the tables and the actual execution plan. Have you checked the plan for warnings or missing indexes or bad estimates vs actual rows?

Comment: @lemon thank you for answer but I need to use nolock as our company policy!

Comment: *nolock is for our policy* - seriously? It sounds like your DBA needs to bone-up on some reading, running everything in `read uncommitted isolation` is a policy for missing, duplicating and corrupting data and more bugs than the Amazon (the rainforest, not the company - probably). If you have a lot of blocking and deadlocking perhaps look at an optimistic isolation level instead.

Comment: For performance questions, we need at a minimum: the full table and index definitions, and please share the Actual query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Without this info the question is not answerable.

Comment: The query is invalid. You join on `b.id`, but you select no `id` in the `b` subquery. Then, why do you join `d`? Do you want to ensure that the `c` rows have a match in `d`? And why do you join `e`? This seems pointless, as you outer join the table, but don't select anything from it,

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity there but I guess you can write your query this way:

```
with c_cte as
(
    select *
      from dbo.c
     where c.type = 'A' and c.onoff = 'on'
       and exists (select 1 from dbo.d where d.id = c.id)
)
SELECT 'your columns'
FROM dbo.a
left outer join c_cte c on c.id = a.code
left outer join dbo.e on e.name = a.name and e.type = 'E'
```

Is the query performing badly or are you just doing "preventative" optimization? Avoid WITH(NOLOCK) and type-hints - it's years since I found any benefit in type-hints and nolock is only for special cases.

Remember that your driving table is A and you join to C & E using an outer join on non-PK columns. I would expect funny execution plans but unless the execution time is "bad" I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the query like this and execute in SQL Server Management Studio

```
SELECT c.id 
     , c.contents
     , c.status
     , c.img
     , c.type
INTO #b
FROM dbo.c
WHERE c.onoff='on' AND c.type='A'; -- c.Type != 'S' is redundant

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX temp_b_id ON #b (id);

SELECT ...
FROM dbo.a a
LEFT OUTER JOIN #b on (a.Id = b.Id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ...
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #b;
```

To solve your problem, you need to create an index that limits the number of logical reads needed to populate #b. This index will be the same that helps the optimizer avoid the clustered index scan when using a subquery. When you've figured that out, you can revert to your existing query and see if it does it correctly.

Note that SQL Server will prefer to NOT look up Ids in an index, and then do Primary Key Lookups to fetch additional data (when the number of lookups exceeds some threshold). This means you may need to create an index where you include `img, status, content` to populate #b. These includes may not be necessary for the subquery version but, again, that would depend on the row count of #b.